# why does a potencial coil in wattmetter influences the pointer rotation

Tags: power, electromagnetism, watts

can somebody tell me,
why does a potential coil in wattmetter influences the pointer rotation.
if the ideal potential coil doesn't have current, it would not generate a magnetic field and it would not exerced ana kind of force.

But for the wattmeter to work, the force experienced by the pointer as to be proportional to the current passing the current coil and the voltage across the potential coil.

Can you try to explain me this, (interaction between voltage coli and current coil).

thanks

Comment: Miguel, if English is not your first language then please state this in your user profile and we will help you. Your post has spelling and formatting errors. Are you asking about a kW meter or a kWh meter (although the principle of operation will be the same)?

Comment: @Transistor Yes not first Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you try to explain me this

[image]

[Picture source](http://engineering.electrical-equipment.org/others/how-does-a-wattmeter-work-back-to-basics.html)

When there is no power taken by the load, the pointer will be vertical - small springs in the mechanism work to provide a "zeroing" mechanical force.

As real power is consumed by the load the two current coils provide a north south magnetic field that the voltage coil attempts to align with. More current or more voltage means the alignment is better and, depending on flow of power, the needle points more to the left full-scale or more to the righ full-scale.

For AC it works the same except you must consider the phase angle between voltage and current. Should the phase angle between voltage and current be +/- 90 degrees there is no average net force produced by the alternating magnetic fields in the coils and the needle remains vertical.

Comment: the influence of the voltage coli in the rotation of the pointer is because of the small current that passes for the voltage coil or some how the tension of the voltage coil and the "Voltage Resistor( the one in series with Vc)", will influence the inductance of the current coil?

Comment: The small current through the large number of turns in the voltage coil produce the magnetic field that interacts with the larger current (but fewer turns) in the current coils. The resistor is there to limit current in the voltage coil should DC voltage be applied.